# change color to bar plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have the matrix A and I make a barplot

```
A = rand(15,9);
h = bar(A);
```

now I would like to color each group of bars (each row of A) according to the colormap "colorset" defined below

```
colorset = [0   0   1;...
1   0   0;...
0   1   0;...
0   0   0.172413793103448;...
1   0.103448275862069   0.724137931034483;...
1   0.827586206896552   0;...
0   0.344827586206897   0;...
0.517241379310345   0.517241379310345   1;...
0.620689655172414   0.310344827586207   0.275862068965517]
```

I try to do something like

```
set(get(h,'children'),'cdata', A );
colormap(colorset);
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help:

```
   for hi = 1:numel(h)
        set(h(hi), 'FaceColor', colorset(hi,:))
   end
```

**Before (orginal colors):**

[image]

**After (new colors):**
[image]